# How to diagnose dotnet process consuming high CPU?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core process running in Kubernetes. Suddenly something went wrong and CPU usage jumped from 8% to 100% and settled at that level. Memory usage did not change so it looks like an infinite loop in a thread.

What instruments can I use to diagnose what is happening in the process?

What should I do to be able to diagnose such problems in the future?

Comment: @D-Shih why did you changed original title to that strange something?

Comment: I modify the title because this is a question, so I rewrite `why` in the first of title, but My English may not be good. apologize for that

Comment: I write another version titled `How can we diagnose high CPU consuming process in .net core`. would that be better? or you can change the original title if you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.net core support some command that let us diagnose CPU high or Memory problem.

first, install tools

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-trace
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-counters
```

then we can use `dotnet-trace ps` to get the process id that we want to trace.

then use `dotnet-counters` command we can see the process using resource situations.

```
dotnet-counters monitor -p 22884 --refresh-interval 1
```

- `-p`: which process id you want to trace
- `--refresh-interval`: How often to refresh the monitor screen from commandline window (unit is second)

> if you want to only focus on  cpu-usage you can try to add this parameter `--counters System.Runtime[cpu-usage]`

when we use the above command we will get a lot of Runtime information that can help us to diagnose from your process.

```
[System.Runtime]
% Time in GC since last GC (%)                          
Allocation Rate (B / 1 sec)                             
CPU Usage (%)                                           
Exception Count (Count / 1 sec)                         
GC Committed Bytes (MB)                                 
GC Fragmentation (%)                                    
GC Heap Size (MB)                                       
Gen 0 GC Count (Count / 1 sec)                          
Gen 0 Size (B)                                          
Gen 1 GC Count (Count / 1 sec)                          
Gen 1 Size (B)                                        
Gen 2 GC Count (Count / 1 sec)                        
Gen 2 Size (B)                                        
IL Bytes Jitted (B)                                   
LOH Size (B)                                           
Monitor Lock Contention Count (Count / 1 sec)           
Number of Active Timers                                 
Number of Assemblies Loaded                             
Number of Methods Jitted                                
POH (Pinned Object Heap) Size (B)                       
ThreadPool Completed Work Item Count (Count / 1 sec)    
ThreadPool Queue Length                                 
ThreadPool Thread Count                                 
Time spent in JIT (ms / 1 sec)                          
Working Set (MB)
```

more detail you can see [Debug high CPU usage in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-highcpu?tabs=windows) & [dotnet-counters](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/main/documentation/dotnet-counters-instructions.md)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the `dotnet-trace`! I will give it a try.

Comment: After spending some time I did managed to install dotnet tools inside of my Pod and dotnet-trace worked perfectly for me. I've spotted a bug causing an infinite loop.